# appsettings.json | ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1 | Value must be one of the following types: string

Tags: json, asp.net-core-mvc, connection-string, appsettings

I'm working on a ASP.NET Core MVC project, it actually works perfectly, but those ConnectionStrings are highlighted. (As you can see on the following image)

[image]

& the only thing I have is this message :

*Value must be one of the following types: string*

*DefaultConnection Connection string confirguration. Each connection string has a name specified by its JSON property name.
Type: string*

I've tried to restart Visual Studio, but they are still there.
Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I've just found the soluce :

`ConnectionStrings` as to be like this `connectionStrings`

BEFORE :

[image]

THEN :

[image]

Comment: You can even use a name "CoNnecTionStRings" if you like it more. But if want to use Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")  of startup option that included in framework you have to call it "ConnectionStrings". If you use another name you can do this only using Configuration["CoNnecTionStRings:DefaultConnection: ConnectionString" ]) that is much more complicated.

Comment: I'm actually calling it that way : Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection:ConnectionString")

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string section should be like this (it is MS SQL server, but you have to change them accordingly for oracle):

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;",

 "Web": "Data Source=22.182.22.333;initial catalog=DB;Integrated Security=False;User ID=AdminApp;Password=AppUser;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096;"
    },
```

And remove  the provider name lines. You probably don't need them or they should be included inside of connection strings.

UPDATE:

I just tested in the VS2019 this name for connection strings, it works the same way. It seems like in appsetting.json names of sections can be in any case -  low or upper.

```
CoNnecTionStRings: {
      "DefaultConnection": ....,
        '''''
 },
```